# Link to section of a webpage in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

What is the easiest way to obtain link to a particular section of a document? For example, if you want to link to http://www.somepage.html#basic_facts you seem to need to either dig into the HTML or guess the name of the section. Are there any Firefox add-ons to help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this [Named Anchors](http://jpeters.no-ip.com/extensions/?page=fx_na) Firefox extension that will add a new tab to the 'Page Info' dialog box.

> This extension adds a new tab to Page Info with information about the named anchors in the current document.
>
> Drag & Drop the address of a named anchor to the browser to open the page at the specified anchor

[image: screenshot]

There also seems to be an alternate extension, [Show anchors](http://jpeters.no-ip.com/extensions/?page=fx_na) that may be a bit easier to use.

Comment: Show anchors links to named Named Anchors

Comment: Well that sure is embarrassing